# .net uploading file then unable to retrieve - directory path?

Tags: .net, excel, excel-interop

I can currently upload an excel file to an uploads directory:

```
FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/ExcelImport.xls"))
```

But when I try to retrieve it to open it, it reports that it can't find it:

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("~/Uploads/ExcelImport.xlsx")
```

---

Error message:

> '~/Uploads/ExcelImport.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of
>   the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently
>   used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or
>   deleted.

---

Anyone know what might be the problem or seen this before?

Comment: You're saving as `xls` then trying to open `xlsx`.  Look at your code above.

Comment: Ok sorry that was a mistake, I do have both as ~/Uploads/ExcelImport.xlsx and it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/ExcelImport.xls"))

Comment: Yeah sorry, could tick it initially. Thanks:)